# How many zeds does a mega zed count as?

Tags: atom-zombie-smasher

I've been playing a bit of Atom Zombie Smasher lately. I'm pretty sure that I'm losing, as the zeds have amassed enough points for mega zeds to start appearing (and I'm not exactly keeping up).

That aside, I was wondering how many kills are registered for a unit when it kills a mega zed, as I am pondering ways to get the "Destroy 50 Zed in one XXX explosion", where XXX is one of the available types of explosives.

If mega zeds register as several kills, they would provide a lucrative venue to getting said achievements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tested this in my copy just now, by adding a mod that caused them to spawn at the start of the game, and it doesn't seem like they count significantly more than regular zombies.   I bombarded the mega zed with artillery until he died, and I got credit for 2 "regular zombie" kills.

I had a tough time with the game until I turned on a few of the options to make it easier.  If you can pick your own squads, you can take barricades and the weaponry that you want to use for the achievements.  You can still get the achievements even if the difficulty settings are turned down.

I found that it was possible with the barricades to funnel several zombie hordes into one "kill zone" which would make it easier to get them in one go.  The mines are probably going to be the worst, as you can't control when they detonate.

Since your squads level up, you may want to wait a bit until you've got some larger infestations to deal with before you attempt these achievements.  I heavily preferred the artillery, so I don't have most of the dynamite/mine achievements.

Comment: Thanks for all the useful tips (though I was just giving my question some context, this would actually make a great answer for a question focusing on the achievements)! I'll give someone a chance to step forward with a more definitive answer to the question, though.

Comment: @Aubergine, certainly.  If I have some time to test later, I'll try to reproduce my assumptions.  There are probably some mods that would make this a quick test;  I've just got family in town today :)

Comment: @Aubergine, I tested it further this evening and it appears to count as 2 zombies.  Not that awesome from an achievement perspective, unfortunately :(

Comment: What can I say, you take your answers seriously. +1 for your extensive efforts.